# Shared service not fetching data after redirect back to the same page in Angular 7

Tags: angular7

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sharedData.profileData.subscribe((data: any) => {
         this.userDetails = data;
    });
 }
```

above code retrieve data when only page reloading. It gives me the old data when I redirect back to the same page after I add some data into the database from another component(page). If I reload the page, the service will give me correct data(Recent Data).

Ex -

- scenario 1 - reload the home page
- ```
     home page shows data = skills(Software Developer", "Photographer")

       skills: (2) ["Software Developer", "Photographer"]
  ```
- scenario 2 - redirect to add skill page
- scenario 3 - add a new skill(let's say Designer) and redirect back to
  the home page component
- scenario 4 - show only the old data
- ```
       data = skills(Software Developer", "Photographer")
  ```
- ```
            skills: (2) ["Software Developer","Photographer"]
  ```
- ```
       Error - It's not showing newly added skill(Designer)
  ```
- ```
       It Should be skills: (3) ["Software Developer", "Photographer",Designer]
  ```

Shared Data Service tsfile

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SharedDataService {

  private profileDataSource = new BehaviorSubject('');
  profileData = this.profileDataSource.asObservable();

  private publicProfileDataSource = new BehaviorSubject('');
  publicProfileData = this.publicProfileDataSource.asObservable();

  private skillDataSource = new BehaviorSubject('');
  skillData = this.skillDataSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  updateProfileData(data: any) {
    this.profileDataSource.next(data);
  }

  addSkillData(data: any) {
    const emitDataObj: any = {
      type: 'ADD',
      data: data
    };
    this.skillDataSource.next(emitDataObj);
  }

  updateSkillData(data: any) {
    const emitDataObj: any = {
      type: 'UPDATE',
      data: data
    };
    this.skillDataSource.next(emitDataObj);
  }

  updatePublicProfileData(data: any) {
    this.publicProfileDataSource.next(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: At a minimum you should also include the implementation `sharedData.profileData`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @lgor ngOnInit() {} is  not invoke if you are navigate to same page you have to subscribe to router changes

Comment: @igor I added the code please have a look.Thanks